# how to make 52-week participation bar graphs like Github has done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, svg, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make bar graphs similar to how Github does it for showing how many commits or how many people are watching repositories, e.g, https://github.com/popular/watched.

Does anyone know what library they used to make it?

**UPDATE** I wanted to re-open this question if possible. Re-investigating this, the solutions below while awesome in their own right, seem a little too involved for what I'm looking for.

I've switched to using this nice Nettuts tutorial which draws a single bar graph but I'm having trouble adapting it to draw multiple bar graphs. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/fun-with-canvas-create-a-jquery-graph-plugin/

I've made a fiddle where I've manually added code to deal with a 2nd graph but I believe I need some for loops to make this work for a variable number of graphs. Here's that fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/zHH76/

might someone be able to edit this fiddle to tackle this question?

Comment: Do you need to know how Github got its numbers, or merely how (given the appropriate numbers) the bar graphs got generated?

Comment: only how bar graphs are generated, thanks

Comment: see http://bitpshr.info/gitgraph

Comment: thanks, can't see where on GitGraph to input the data, thoughts?

Comment: Gitgraph takes a username and repo and makes the XHR request to grab the data, THEN renders the graph. If you already have the data, I can update gitgraph tonight to fit your needs. You can also just glance at the source (<100 lines) and see what I do inside the XHR callback, it's exactly what you need!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look into [d3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/).  There are several examples of how you can take an array in JavaScript and turn it into a graph like that.

Here is one (more advance) example: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/population.html
And here is another example that is closer to what you want: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html

**EDIT**

The actual code that Git Hub uses to create the graphs looks something like this:

```
GitHub.ParticipationGraph = (function(){
  function b(target){
    this.el = target;
    this.onSuccess = $.proxy(this.onSuccess, this);
    this.canvas = this.el.getContext("2d");
    this.refresh();
  }

  b.prototype.barWidth = 7;

  b.prototype.barMaxHeight = 20;

  b.prototype.getUrl = function(){
    return $(this.el).data("source");
  };

  b.prototype.setData = function(data){
    this.data = data;
    if (data == null || data.all == null || data.owner == null) {
      this.data = null;
    }
    this.scale = this.getScale(this.data);
  };

  b.prototype.getScale = function(data){
    var mx, i;
    if (data == null) return;
    mx = data.all[0];
    for(i = 0; i < data.all.length; i++) {
      if (data.all[i] > mx) {
        mx = data.all[i];
      }
    }
    return mx >= this.barMaxHeight ? (this.barMaxHeight-.1)/mx : 1;
  };

  b.prototype.refresh = function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: this.getUrl(),
      dataType: "json",
      success: this.onSuccess
    });
  };

  b.prototype.onSuccess = function(data){
    this.setData(data);
    this.draw();
  };

  b.prototype.draw = function(){
    if (this.data == null) return;
    this.drawCommits(this.data.all, "#cacaca");
    this.drawCommits(this.data.owner, "#336699");
  };

  b.prototype.drawCommits = function(data, color){
    var i, width, height, x, y;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      width = this.barWidth;
      height = data[i] * this.scale;
      x = i * (this.barWidth + 1);
      y = this.barMaxHeight - height;
      this.canvas.fillStyle = color;
      this.canvas.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }
  };

  return b;
})();
```

Basically, they are calling the `data-source` tag located on the canvas, which returns some JSON that represents the amount of work/participation/watches (or whatever metric they are calculating) and then they go through each returned value and call `this.canvas.fillRect` with the predefined width (`(Screensize.width/52) - (paddingLeft + paddingRight)`) and the height from the JSON returned

Comment: thanks Joe, one question: isnt d3.js SVG-based whereas doesn't it look like Github's graphs are displayed using canvas tags?

Comment: Updated with exactly how they are doing it

Comment: @timpeterson D3.js transforms data into DOM nodes and attributes. While it can be used with SVG to great effect, you can also use it with simple HTML elements (e.g. `<div>`) and their CSS properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try [morris](http://oesmith.github.com/morris.js/) for displaying time series data.

Also [Timeplot](http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeplot/).